# How to limit columns shown with tkinter treeview?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, treeview, ttk

I have a function that displays a treeview window, with a provided list from the user. I had built in a horizontal and vertical scrollbar to scroll through. However, how do I limit the amount of columns displayed? If to many columns are given to the function you must make the window larger to view, I don't want that, I would like it to stop at that width and then allow for scrolling to do the rest. Is this possible? I've attached my code with a sample function.

Thanks in advance

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk 

def Display_Results(list_of_values):
    '''
    This will disply your results in a way similar to excel would, headers then values below them

    Sample list: testlist=[['A', 'B', 'C'], [1 , 2, 3], [4, '' ,5], [7, 8, 9]] 
    Use the sample list to show how values will be displayed 

    :param list_of_values: A list with lists, the first list must be the headers. Then the following lists the values for the headers.

    '''
    root=tk.Tk() #Makes window object
    root.config(width=900,height=400, bg='grey') #size of window, and background color



    tree = ttk.Treeview(root, selectmode="extended",columns=list_of_values[0])
    vsb = tk.Scrollbar(orient="vertical", command=tree.yview)
    hsb=tk.Scrollbar(orient="horizontal", command=tree.xview)
    tree.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set, xscrollcommand=hsb.set)

    vsb.place(x=100,y=300)
    hsb.place(x=300,y=310)


    tree.heading("#0", text="Data")
    tree.column("#0",minwidth=0,width=100, anchor='c')

    for x in list_of_values[0]:
        tree.heading(x, text=x)   
        tree.column(x,minwidth=0,width=100, anchor='c') 

    for y in range(1, len(list_of_values)):
        tree.insert("" , y-1,    text=("Data " + str(y)), values=list_of_values[y])




    tree.place(x=0,y=0)

    root.mainloop() #needed to keep the window displayed

testlist=[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'], [1 , 2, 3], [4, '', 5], [7, 8, 9], [1 , 2, 3], [4, 5], [7, 8, 9], [1 , 2, 3], [4, 5], [7, 8, 9], [1 , 2, 3], [4, 5], [7, 8, 9], [1 , 2, 3], [4, 5], [7, 8, 9], [1 , 2, 3], [4, 5], [7, 8, 9], [1 , 2, 3], [4, 5], [7, 8, 9], [1 , 2, 3], [4, 5], [7, 8, 9], [1 , 2, 3], [4, 5], [7, 8, 9]] 
Display_Results(testlist)
```